# Ist "Zuhause" ein Relikt eines nicht mehr existenten Kasus?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Jemand erzählte mir mal, daß „Zuhause“ ein Überbleibsel eines Kasus (Lokativ?) ist, der aus dem modernen Deutsch längst verschwunden ist.

Ich weiß, daß Protogermanisch noch ein paar Kasus mehr enthielt. Aber meine Suche im Internet konnte keinen Hinweis darauf finden, ob die obere Aussage wahr ist.

Könnte es vielleicht noch mehr solcher Relikte in der deutschen Sprache geben?

Comment: Hint: Google ngrams kennt das Wort *zuhause* nicht aus älteren Büchern als  etwa 1750. Es scheint zumindestens nach dieser Quelle also ziemlich neu zu sein (mir persönlich erscheint das allerdings unwahrscheinlich).